# Creating and using iOS settings.bundle values with JavaScript in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins, settings.bundle

**Is it possible to create a section in the iPhone settings app, using PhoneGap (v1.4.1)?**

I cannot find anything pertinent in the PhoneGap API.
My aim would be to use the user-set values in JavaScript.

I imagine that if PhoneGap does not currently have this functionality, it is possible to perform this task with a PhoneGap plugin.

Does anyone know of a current plugin that might enable Settings.bundle creation, and reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use applicationPreferences plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences

Comment: The plugin above is far from perfect, but it will certainly get you started

Comment: Looks like what I'm after.  Thanks!