# PhoneGap iOS App configuration menu

Tags: ios, cordova

I've create an application for iPad using PhoneGap, and I would like to create a configuration menu for the application. For iOS application is possible to let the iOS creates that interface (it will be located in the settings under the ***Apps*** section) just like what Skype, Talking Tom applications uses.

So I would like to make the same thing, taking in consideration I'm developping using phonegap and not Objective-C, but I can also do some objective-c to let it work if needed.

Thank you very much for your time reading and/or answering :)

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you give a more definite statement of the problem? What's stopping you from creating the menu you want? What have you tried?

Comment: thanks Caleb for your time :) actually I didn't knew anywhere to start from so, I thought I could ask here, in meanwhile I found that I can make what I want with adding a Settings.bundle to my application, but I still cannot figure out how to access it from my application using phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to access the values that the user sets using your Settings bundle:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger stars = [defaults integerForKey:@"numberOfStars"];
double velocity = [defaults doubleForKey:@"shipVelocity"];
```

and so forth. I'm not aware of a plugin for PhoneGap that makes user preferences available to your JavaScript, but once you know how to access the settings in Objective-C you should be able to provide that data to your scripts.

Comment: one more question please, how can I set the setting bundle icon ? for the instant it shows the phonegap icon

Comment: The icon displayed for your app's page in the Settings app is normally a smaller version of your app's icon, so if you change your app's icon, the icon in Settings should change as well. If you provide a `Icon-Small.png` file in your app's bundle, Settings will use that.

Comment: Looks like there is a PhoneGap plugin that lets you read and set values via JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738451/creating-and-using-ios-settings-bundle-values-with-javascript-in-phonegap